# Error en clase typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente problema con una function typescript

```
[ts] Property 'notificaciones' does not exist on type 'typeof Alertas'.
```

necesito utilizar la funcion llamada mensaje en un componente pero al momento de establecer la funcion como public static me aparece ese mensaje, mientras tanto si le quito el static no manda ese error.

el codigo es el siguiente

```
import { NotificationService } from "../shared/utils/notification.service";

export class Alertas {

    constructor(private notificaciones:NotificationService) { }

    public static  mensaje() {
        this.notificaciones.smallBox({
            title: "Sistema Minutas",
            content: "Los datos se guardaron correctamente",
            color: "#739E73",
            timeout: 4000,
            iconSmall: "fa fa-check",
        });
    } 
}
```

notificaciones.service este es el codigo de mi servicio

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  constructor() {
  }

  smallBox(data, cb?) {
    $.smallBox(data, cb)
  }

  bigBox(data, cb?) {
    $.bigBox(data, cb)
  }

  smartMessageBox(data, cb?) {
    $.SmartMessageBox(data, cb)
  }

}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59842/discussion-on-question-by-gonzalo-alberto-error-en-clase-typescript).

Answer (score 1):

Un método `static` solo puede acceder a otros miembros `static` de la clase.

Efectivamente como mencionas si le quitas el static no debería darte ningun error.

```
import { NotificationService } from "../shared/utils/notification.service";

export class Alertas {

    constructor(private notificaciones: NotificationService) { }

    public mensaje() {
        this.notificaciones.smallBox({
            title: "Sistema Minutas",
            content: "Los datos se guardaron correctamente",
            color: "#739E73",
            timeout: 4000,
            iconSmall: "fa fa-check",
        });

    } 
}
```

Para luego llamar a este método deberás instanciar la clase `Alertas` de la sgte manera.

```
// Asumiendo que ya tienes una instancia de NotificationServices
let alertas = new Alertas(notificaciones);
alertas.mensaje();
```

Comment: me dice que no existe notificaciones

Comment: let alertas = new Alertas(notificaciones);
alertas.mensaje();

Comment: A su vez tienes que instanciar esa clase o pasarle el objeto correspondiente. Te recomiendo que entiendas primero como funciona la programación orientada a objetos para que comprendas bien los conceptos

Comment: gracias por el tip,

Comment: podrias ayudarme?